# Is there a photo mode in Pokemon ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In XY, there were NPCs that would take your picture and allow you to save the photo to camera roll.  Does this feature return in Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire?  If so, where can you take pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Photo Spots do not return in Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire, and there is no way to take a picture outside of Pokemon Contests.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Photography#Pok.C3.A9mon_Omega_Ruby_and_Alpha_Sapphire) says is:

> In Pokémon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire, players will be able to take pictures of their Pokémon during the appeals round of **Pokémon Contest Spectaculars**.